# Como escrevo uma informação na mesma linha sem criar uma nova?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa, e quero que toda vez que o valor da variável mude, apareça na mesma linha e não que crie linhas novas com o mesmo conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teria como você [edit] o post e dar um exemplo de como seria a saída desejada?

Comment: pronto! adicionei mais uma foto.

Answer (score 4):

Limpa a tela e recria oque esta nela, isto é uma das soluções possíveis

```
import os
os.system('cls');
```